# Деление методом вычитания. С++

Tags: c++, циклы

В общем надо поделить два двоичных числа. Я написал код который делит их методом вычитания, т.е. просто в цикле while вычитает одно из другого пока не станет равным нулю. Но почему то код не работает, просто когда я выбираю деление, то в консоли просто мигает курсор и ничего не происходит, никаких ошибок или остановок, просто пусто. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем у меня ошибка?
Вот та функция с делением:

`bin1`, `bin2` - двоичные числа.

```
void Chas(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int quot = 0;
    int a = ToDec(bin1);
    int b = ToDec(bin2);
    while (a >= b);
    {
        a = strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) - strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2);
        bin1 = ToBin1(to_string(a), 10);
        quot += 1;
    }

    cout << "Quotient" << quot << endl << "blabla " << a << endl;
    system ("pause");
    system ("cls");
}
```

А вот весь код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

string ToBin1(string st1, int ss11);
string ToBin2(string st2, int ss12);
int ToDec(string r);
void Summ(string bin1, string bin2);
void Diff(string bin1, string bin2);
void Mult(string bin1, string bin2);
void Chas(string bin1, string bin2);
int Comp(string bin1, string bin2);


int main()
{
    int  ss11, ss12;
    string st1, st2;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");//руссификатор

    int action=0;//Переменные целого типа


    cout << "Введите первое число и его систему счисления: " << endl;
    cin >> st1 >> ss11;
    cout << ToBin1(st1,ss11) << endl;

    cout << "Введите второе число: " << endl;
    cin >> st2 >> ss12;
    cout << ToBin2(st2,ss12) << endl;

    bool flag = true;
    while(flag)
    {

        cout << "------------------------Menu--------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Выберите действие: " << endl;
        cout << "1)Сложить числа " << endl;
        cout << "2)Вычесть числа " << endl;
        cout << "3)Умножить числа " << endl;
        cout << "4)Разделить числа " << endl;
        cout << "5)Сравнить числа " << endl;
        cout << "6)Выход из программы " << endl;
        cout << "7)Ввести новые числа " << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Ваш выбор :";//Запрос выбора пункта меню
        cin >> action;//Ввод выбора
        system ("cls");//очистка консоли
        switch (action) 
        {
        case 1: Summ(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)); break;
        case 2: Diff(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)); break;
        case 3: Mult(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)); break;
        case 4: Chas(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)); break;
        case 5: Comp(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)); break;
        case 6: 
            {
            exit(0); 
            break;
            flag = false;
            }
        case 7: 
            {
            cout << "Введите первое число и его систему счисления: " << endl;
            cin >> st1 >> ss11;
            cout << ToBin1(st1,ss11) << endl;

            cout << "Введите второе число: " << endl;
            cin >> st2 >> ss12;
            cout << ToBin2(st2,ss12) << endl;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

string ToBin1(string st1, int ss11)
{

    int i, k, p, dec;
    string bin1;
    string digits[16] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    string digits1 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    for (size_t i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = digits1.find(tolower(st1[i]));
        if (pos == string::npos || pos >= ss11)
        {
            cerr << "Wrong symbol in value " << st1 << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    dec = 0;
    p = st1.length() - 1;


    for (i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(st1[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(ss11,p);
        } 

    do 
        { 
        bin1.insert(0, digits[dec % 2]); 
        dec /= 2; 
        } while (dec != 0); 


    return bin1;

}

string ToBin2(string st2, int ss12)
{

    int i, k, p, dec;
    string bin2;
    string digits[16] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    string digits1 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    for (size_t i = 0; i < st2.length(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = digits1.find(tolower(st2[i]));
        if (pos == string::npos || pos >= ss12)
        {
            cerr << "Wrong symbol in value " << st2 << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    dec = 0;
    p = st2.length() - 1;


    for (i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(st2[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(ss12,p);
        } 

    do 
        { 
        bin2.insert(0, digits[dec % 2]); 
        dec /= 2; 
        } while (dec != 0); 


        return bin2;

}

int ToDec(string r)
{
    long long int dec, p, k;
    dec = 0;
    p = r.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(r[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(2,p);
        } 
    return dec;
}

void Mult(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int p, k;
    string r(bin1.length()+bin2.length()-1,'0');

    for (int i = bin1.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = bin2.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            r[i+j] += (bin1[i] != '0' && bin2[j] != '0');
        }
    }

    for (int i = r.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        r[i-1] += (r[i]-'0')/2;
        r[i] = (r[i]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }

    while(r[0] > '1')
    {
        r = "0" + r;
        r[0] += (r[1]-'0')/2;
        r[1] = (r[1]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }


    cout << r << endl << "The multiplication of these numbers is: " << ToDec(r) << endl;
    system("pause");
    system ("cls");
}   

void Summ(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) + strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2);
    cout << ToBin1(to_string(temp), 10) << endl << temp << endl;
    system("pause");
    system ("cls");
}

void Diff(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) - strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2);
    cout << ToBin1(to_string(temp), 10) << endl << temp << endl;
    system("pause");
    system ("cls");
}

int Comp(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int la = bin1.length();
    int lb = bin2.length();

    int flag = -1;
    size_t aLoc=-1,bLoc=-1;

    if (la == lb)
    {

        do
        {
            aLoc = bin1.find("1", aLoc + 1);
            bLoc = bin2.find("1", bLoc + 1);
            if(aLoc < bLoc)
            {
                cout << bin1 << " > " << bin2 << endl << ToDec(bin1) << " > " << ToDec(bin2) << endl;
                system("pause");
                system ("cls");
                return 0;
            }
            else if(aLoc>bLoc)
            {
                cout << bin1 << " < " << bin2 << endl << ToDec(bin1) << " < " << ToDec(bin2) << endl;
                system("pause");
                system ("cls");
                return 0;
            }
        }while(aLoc == bLoc && aLoc != string::npos);
         cout << bin1 << " = " << bin2 << endl << ToDec(bin1) << "=" << ToDec(bin2) << endl;
         system("pause");
         system ("cls");
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (la > lb)
            cout << bin1 << " > " << bin2 << endl << ToDec(bin1) << " > " << ToDec(bin2) << endl;
        if (la < lb)
            cout << bin1 << " < " << bin2 << endl << ToDec(bin1) << " < " << ToDec(bin2) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    system ("cls");

}

void Chas(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int quot = 0;
    int a = ToDec(bin1);
    int b = ToDec(bin2);
    while (a >= b);
    {
        a = strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) - strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2);
        bin1 = ToBin1(to_string(a), 10);
        quot += 1;
    }

    cout << "Quotient" << quot << endl << "blabla " << a << endl;
    system ("pause");
    system ("cls");
}
```

Comment: Возьмите отладчик и посмотрите что же у вас не работает и почему.

Comment: можете кинуть какой нибудь материал по дебаггеру в vs 2012 пожалуйста? Я просто им пользоваться не умею

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A что просили

Comment: Хотя отладчики во времена первых машин отсутствовали, но отладочный вывод использовали уже тогда :) Ну просто если не умеете отладчиком - впишите в интересующих местах что-то типа `"cout<<"Line "<<__LINE__ << " Var = " << var << endl;` - и смотрите на экране, чему равно значение той или иной переменной в той или иной строке...

Comment: да я что то отладчиком проходить пытаюсь, но все равно на цикле while не понимаю нифига почему пусто в консоли...

Comment: Все великолепно. Ошибку нашел, спасибо вам) после while точку с запятой поставил =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (a >= b);
```

проблема в данной строчке.
Вы входите в бесконечный цикл. ; - лишняя

Comment: да, спасибо, вчера уже сам нашел :)